# I moved wp site from server to local host but i cant run it now

Tags: wordpress, localhost

I moved a wp website from server to local host and i run it successfully in first time. But now i wanted to move the same website with new content then i just replaced the DB and wp files in the previous folder but now i cant run the website it shows the below error (download file)

once i try : localhost/8888/websitename

it downloads a file with following scripts:

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', true );

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a plugin or theme conflict. Please attempt to disable all plugins(by rename plugins folder), and use one of the default (Twenty*) themes. If the problem goes away, enable them one by one to identify the source of your troubles.

And this issue also cause by wrong code in .htaccess file. So, please check that too.

Comment: Did you try by disabling all plugins and activate default (Twenty*) themes?

Comment: Yes, still the same thing

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be caused by using invalid/incorrect php/php.ini handler .htaccess code in the root .htaccess file.
    This was my problem.

There could have been a php/php.ini handler code in the wp-admin .htaccess file when the wp-admin .htaccess file should not have any php/php.ini handler code in it.
    The php/php.ini handler .htaccess code should only be in the root .htaccess file. If that was the case I would have tried deleting the wp-admin .htaccess file and see if that solved the problem.

There could be a .htaccess file higher up in the hosting account folder structure that has invalid php/php.ini handler .htaccess code in it.
    That is what I originally checked for in step 1.
    Another problem could be that the hosting provider was upgraded and not configured correctly.

I think this shouldn’t be your first conclusion.
There are a couple other reasons why you may have run into this problem, but I think this is a good start to troubleshooting the problem

Comment: Thanks @vishalPavasiya, i even deleted the .htaccess file but still the problem is there

Comment: can you access wp-admin?
if yes then go to settings->permalink and click save button once and check.


also delete .htaccess file completely from root of folder and check there are no other .htaccess file in folder

if all above not work then put belowe code in htaccess



# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress

Comment: I can not even run the website then how can i access the permalink ? should i create new .htaccess file with the above codes you provided?

Comment: yes create new htaccess and put the code inside of it and try again. also, try after clearing browser cache and cookie